# Apache Pulsar installation in Windows Docker

Tags: apache-pulsar, python-pulsar, pulsar

Could you please help me how to install a local standalone pulsar cluster using windows docker.i have followed the below options.but i  couldn't able to access the pulsar UI

8080 port is already allocated for some other process.so here i'm using 8081 port.

Option 1:

docker run -it -p 6650:6650 -p 8081:8081 --mount source=pulsardata,target=/pulsar/data --mount source=pulsarconf,target=/pulsar/conf apachepulsar/pulsar:2.5.2 bin/pulsar standalone

Option 2:
docker run -it -p 6650:6650 -p 8081:8081 -v "$PWD/data:/pulsar/data".ToLower() apachepulsar/pulsar:2.5.2 bin/pulsar standalone

Using the above two options, i couldn't able to see the INFO  - [main:WebService] - Web Service started at http://127.0.0.1:8081.Also i'm not able to access the following url in the system.

pulsar://localhost:6650

http://localhost:8081

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [mapping](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) between the ports. It is clear that you cannot use 8080 on your side, but the port 8080 should be still used within the container, because this port is used by the service. The correct command is:

```
docker run -it -p 6650:6650 -p 8081:8080 apachepulsar/pulsar:2.5.2 bin/pulsar standalone
```

It makes sense to try it out without the volumes first and add them later.